# Android: Set Random colour background on create

Tags: android, random, colors, background, oncreate

What I want is when I load my app up it to randomly have a certain colored background from a predefined list of strings stored in a values xml file called colours.

What I currently have is one colour set as the background defined through the string colour code using the gui editor in eclipse.

For the life of me can't work out how to get the background to randomly pick one of the 9 strings and display it each time the activity is activated.

Guidance on this would be invaluable.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <item name="blue" type="color">#FF33B5E5</item>
    <item name="purple" type="color">#FFAA66CC</item>
    <item name="green" type="color">#FF99CC00</item>
    <item name="orange" type="color">#FFFFBB33</item>
    <item name="red" type="color">#FFFF4444</item>
    <item name="darkblue" type="color">#FF0099CC</item>
    <item name="darkpurple" type="color">#FF9933CC</item>
    <item name="darkgreen" type="color">#FF669900</item>
    <item name="darkorange" type="color">#FFFF8800</item>
    <item name="darkred" type="color">#FFCC0000</item>

    <integer-array name="androidcolors">
        <item>@color/blue</item>
        <item>@color/purple</item>
        <item>@color/green</item>
        <item>@color/orange</item>
        <item>@color/red</item>
        <item>@color/darkblue</item>
        <item>@color/darkpurple</item>
        <item>@color/darkgreen</item>
        <item>@color/darkorange</item>
        <item>@color/darkred</item>
    </integer-array>

</resources>
```

In onCreate()

```
int[] androidColors = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.androidcolors);
int randomAndroidColor = androidColors[new Random().nextInt(androidColors.length)];
view.setBackgroundColor(randomAndroidColor);
```

Answer (score 6):

There's a much better answer than the ones provided.

If you want a **Truly** random color, "randomly" choosing from a res file doesn't prove to be nearly as robust.

Instead, use this code snippet:

```
  Random rnd = new Random();
    currentStrokeColor = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
```

Comment: i got value -118692481300, out of integer?

Answer (score 4):

I think I could find an easy approach but some how long to implement ,you choose random color from a defined array of colors and than parse that string color to your background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="bright_pink">#FF007F</color>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
    <color name="orange">#FF7F00</color>
    <color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
    <color name="chartreuse">#7FFF00</color>
    <color name="green">#00FF00</color>
    <color name="spring_green">#00FF7F</color>
    <color name="cyan">#00FFFF</color>
    <color name="azure">#007FFF</color>
    <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
    <color name="violet">#7F00FF</color>
    <color name="magenta">#FF00FF</color>
<array name="rainbow">
    <item>@color/bright_pink</item>
    <item>@color/red</item>
    <item>@color/orange</item>
    <item>@color/yellow</item>
    <item>@color/chartreuse</item>
    <item>@color/green</item>
    <item>@color/spring_green</item>
    <item>@color/cyan</item>
    <item>@color/azure</item>
    <item>@color/blue</item>
    <item>@color/violet</item>
    <item>@color/magenta</item>
</array>
```

and than this java code

```
String[] array = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.animals_array);
String randomStr = array[new Random().nextInt(array.length)];

//here you define your layout `

LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.that_linear);

myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(randomStr));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set a variable `Random rnd = new Random();` as a random number (will generate a psuedo-random number between 0 and 1). Then you could say:

```
    if (rnd < 0.09) {
        //pick first colour
    } else if (rnd >= 0.09 && rnd < 0.18) {
        //pick second colour
    } else if (rnd >= 0.18 && rnd < 0.27) {
        //pick second colour    
    } else // etc etc up to 1.0 when you will have 9 options, each with an equal chance of randomly being picked
```

This way, the random number `rnd` will determine which colour the background is each time `onCreate()` is called.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `ColorGenerator` class to get random `color.code`.

snippet given below

```
ColorGenerator generator = ColorGenerator.MATERIAL;

int color=generator.getRandomColor();
```

here you can use the view reference to set color like

```
mUserName.setText("Suraj");

mUserName.setTextColor(color);  //it will populate name with random color each time you open your activity
```

Answer (score -3):

> TRY THIS METHOD SIMPLE AND EASY

```
private boolean isOne = false, isTwo = false, isThree = false, isFour = false, isFive = false;

if(position==0){
            holder.llDate.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.color1));
            holder.view.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.color1));
            isTwo = true;
        }else if(isOne){
            holder.llDate.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.color1));
            holder.view.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.color1));
            isOne = false;
            isTwo = true;
        }else if(isTwo){
            holder.llDate.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.color2));
            holder.view.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.color2));
            isTwo = false;
            isThree = true;
        }else if(isThree){
            holder.llDate.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.color3));
            holder.view.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.color3));
            isThree = false;
            isFour = true;
        }else if(isFour){
            holder.llDate.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.color4));
            holder.view.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.color4));
            isFour = false;
            isFive = true;
        }else if(isFive){
            holder.llDate.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.color5));
            holder.view.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.color5));
            isFive = false;
            isOne = true;
        }
```