# How to set random color

Tags: android, colors, libgdx

this is an extract of my code:

```
Color[] color = new Color[3];
color [0] = Color.red;
color[1] = Color.blue;
color[2] = Color.yellow;
stage.getBatch().setColor(color[rand.nextInt()]);
```

But "color[rand.nextInt()]);" is underlined red. I really don´t know why. There have to be four numbers or instead "Color.BLUE" for example in the brackets but I want to tint the sprite randomly. Therefore I created an array with three colors. I thought by just giving them numbers and using rand.nextInt it would work. What is the mistake?

Comment: this will be helpful to you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284802/how-to-output-a-random-color-from-a-set-of-selected-colors-in-java-android/40373178#40373178

Comment: What is the actual compiler error message given for the code underlined red?

Comment: Error message: "Cannot resolve method 'setColor (java.awt.Color)'

Comment: And what type is returned when you do `stage.getBatch()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate random colors like this:

```
Random rnd = new Random(); 
int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
```

Comment: If I write your code in Android Studio, argb is red, so there's an error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4246418/5354875

Quite the simplest way possible to do it! Also see this answer, it makes you capable of choosing only bright or dark colors when getting random ones.

Comment: I discovered the error: it has to be argb8888. But how can I change the color of a sprite randomly with this code?

Comment: What is sprite? Is it a view?

Comment: Yes, it´s a view. I changed the color of the sprite randomly by tapping on the screen. However, I want to implement a timer for changing the colors. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Please post another question, or edit your question according to your new requirements

Comment: Okay. Another question related to this topic: how can I exclude the colors black and white with your code?

Comment: You can look at the ARGB hex values and exclude white and black by putting a check

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "putting a check"?

Answer (score 1):

Given the error message `Error message: "Cannot resolve method 'setColor (java.awt.Color)'` it looks like you are using the wrong Color class for Libgdx's SpriteBatch.

You need to change your import to `com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color`

Also, to correctly randomly select from your 3 colors, you need to use `rand.nextInt(color.length)` to bound the randomly generated int to the number of elements in your array.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [Semi-random approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55334738/7756492) that make more shiny and fresh colors.

[image]