# How to set random background for cardview?

Tags: android, random, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I currently have an Android recyclerview and a list item for it. In the list item is a cardview for my views. I want to have random backgrounds for each card list this one: [image] 
my cards now have a solid background and I search every where and used any code but couldn't find an example for view like example.

My list item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_view_lead"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/style_lead"
        android:padding="7dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/option"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_option"
            android:tint="@android:color/white" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/large_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                    android:id="@+id/lead_img"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/test_pic"
                    app:riv_border_color="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:riv_border_width="0.1dp"
                    app:riv_corner_radius="100dp"
                    tools:src="@drawable/pic_1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lead_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/standard_margin"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lead_img"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/large_font_size"
                    tools:text="@string/test_name" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lead_city"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/standard_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/large_font_size"
                tools:text="@string/test_city" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/standard_margin">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lead_price"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/large_font_size"
                    tools:text="30$" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/large_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lead_price"
                    android:text="@string/per_hour"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/large_font_size" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/with"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/standard_margin"
                    android:text="@string/with"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/large_font_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lead_vehicle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/with"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/large_font_size"
                    tools:text="@string/car" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/lead_vehicle_img"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lead_vehicle"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/car_img"
                    tools:src="@drawable/ic_car" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: u want to have random colors as your card view background??

Comment: @Moulesh yes. i said in descriptions.

Comment: @A.Heydari what about my old answer ???

Comment: Check my answer it will work...

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/47879588/8325853]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate random colors each time you put a new item in the adapter list
[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280367/android-generate-random-color-on-click)

---

Since you only provided the xml part, I am assuming you have a model where you store the information to display. You can add another property "color" where you can store the random color for each item, and set in on your **onBindViewHolder** method

Comment: @A.Heydari object 'card' should be null and it is causing NullPointerException??  Debugging your code may help you to analyze it!

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/ayushkhare/f501721640ebc6cfc1b0d54fe96901ce)

Answer (score 4):

```
CardView cardView = (CardView)findViewById(R.id.card_view_lead);
cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(getRandomColorCode());

public int getRandomColorCode(){

  Random random = new Random();

  return Color.argb(255, random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256),     random.nextInt(256));

}
```

Comment: can we use random gradient colors?

Answer (score 2):

```
CardView card = (CardView)findViewById(R.id.card_view_lead);
```

in your onbindview holder

```
Random rnd = new Random();
        currentColor = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
    holder.card.setCardBackgroundColor(currentColor);
```

Comment: nullpointerexaption for card.setBackgroundColor(currentColor);

Comment: that means you are not assigning the reference of cardview check updated answer.. Hope you know how to take reference to views from adapter

Answer (score 1):

Create Array in res/values/colour like this

```
<array name="note_neutral_colors">
    <item>#9E9E9E</item>
    <item>#455A64</item>
    <item>#607D8B</item>
</array>

<array name="note_accent_colors">
    <item>#039BE5</item>
    <item>#3D51B3</item>
    <item>#689f38</item>
    <item>#FD7044</item>
</array>
```

In Your Adapter Class

```
holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(noticeModel.getColor());
```

Model Class

```
//Variable
int color;
//Cunstructor
this.color=color;  
///and generate Getter Setter
```

Do this Your Main Class.java

```
private static int getRandomColor(Context context) {
    int[] colors;
    if (Math.random() >= 0.6) {
        colors = context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.note_accent_colors);
    } else {
        colors = context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.note_neutral_colors);
    }
    return colors[((int) (Math.random() * colors.length))];
}
```

call this method with string request like this

```
yourModel = new Your_Model(data1,data2,data3,getRandomColor(YourActivity.this));
```

Comment: where must i use : yourModel = new Your_Model(data1,data2,data3,getRandomColor(YourActivity.this));

Comment: @A.Heydari It used in your activity where you input data into model.

Comment: This answer works really well for when you are using RecyclerView. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to write some logic to produce random colors and then use it like

```
CardView card = (CardView)findViewById(R.id.card);
card.setCardBackgroundColor(color);
```

To produce random colors, solutions are already available on Stack Overflow, please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25923116/android-set-random-colour-background-on-create) link.

Comment: i tried this but i did got an error 'null pointer exception'; if you have an idea about random color in java codes send me please

Answer (score 0):

Normally we can do like this,
Colors.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <item name="blue" type="color">#FF33B5E5</item>
    <item name="purple" type="color">#FFAA66CC</item>
    <item name="green" type="color">#FF99CC00</item>
    <item name="orange" type="color">#FFFFBB33</item>
    <item name="red" type="color">#FFFF4444</item>
    <item name="darkblue" type="color">#FF0099CC</item>
    <item name="darkpurple" type="color">#FF9933CC</item>
    <item name="darkgreen" type="color">#FF669900</item>
    <item name="darkorange" type="color">#FFFF8800</item>
    <item name="darkred" type="color">#FFCC0000</item>

    <integer-array name="androidcolors">
        <item>@color/blue</item>
        <item>@color/purple</item>
        <item>@color/green</item>
        <item>@color/orange</item>
        <item>@color/red</item>
        <item>@color/darkblue</item>
        <item>@color/darkpurple</item>
        <item>@color/darkgreen</item>
        <item>@color/darkorange</item>
        <item>@color/darkred</item>
    </integer-array>

</resources>
```

And do this in your onCreateView(),

```
CardView card_view_lead;
         card_view_lead= (CardView) findViewById(R.id.card_view_lead);

        int[] androidColors = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.androidcolors);
        int randomAndroidColor = androidColors[new Random().nextInt(androidColors.length)];
        card_view_lead.setBackgroundColor(randomAndroidColor);
```

If you don't want to use color array then you can use like this in your onCreateView() or onCreate(),

```
mCardViewTop.setCardBackgroundColor(getRandomColor());
public static int getRandomColor() {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        return Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired behavior where the colors are not repeated, and each item has a unique color based on its position, you can modify the code as follows:

```
<color name="cardColor1">#FFB2B2</color> <!-- light red -->
<color name="cardColor2">#FFD9B2</color> <!-- light orange -->
<color name="cardColor3">#FFFFB2</color> <!-- light yellow -->
<color name="cardColor4">#B2FFB2</color> <!-- light green -->
<color name="cardColor5">#B2FFFF</color> <!-- light blue-green -->
<color name="cardColor6">#B2B2FF</color> <!-- light blue -->
<color name="cardColor7">#D9B2FF</color> <!-- light lavender -->
<color name="cardColor8">#FFB2F5</color> <!-- light magenta -->
<color name="cardColor9">#FFD9E8</color> <!-- light pink -->
<color name="cardColor10">#FFE8D9</color> <!-- light peach -->
<color name="cardColor11">#E8FFD9</color> <!-- light lime -->
<color name="cardColor12">#D9E8FF</color> <!-- light sky blue -->


<array name="cardColors">
    <item>@color/cardColor1</item>
    <item>@color/cardColor2</item>
    <item>@color/cardColor3</item>
    <item>@color/cardColor4</item>
    <item>@color/cardColor5</item>
    <item>@color/cardColor6</item>
    <item>@color/cardColor7</item>
    <item>@color/cardColor8</item>
    <item>@color/cardColor9</item>
    <item>@color/cardColor10</item>
    <item>@color/cardColor11</item>
    <item>@color/cardColor12</item>
</array>
```

Then, modify the method to choose the color based on the current position while ensuring that the same color is not repeated:

```
    int lastColorIndex = -1;
    int[] androidColors = context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.cardColors);
    int colorIndex = (position % androidColors.length); // get the color index based on the position
    if (colorIndex == lastColorIndex) { // if the same color as the last item is selected, increment the index
        colorIndex = (colorIndex + 1) % androidColors.length;
    }
    cvCard.setCardBackgroundColor(androidColors[colorIndex]);
```

Comment: int position = 1....................;