# How to randomly generate a string and color that string randomly in Android studio

Tags: java, android, random, text, kotlin

I'm trying to make a program generate a text randomly and let that text be color randomly too but I don't know how. Can be in either Java or Kotlin.

Comment: Look for some tutorials

Comment: Please do Google this is the simple question, you definitely get the answer.

Comment: I want to make like this
random number == 1
print("RED")
number == 2
blue
Becuase I want to create the game Type the color name and change to another color.

Comment: Check out the `switch` statement in Java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Set Random colour background on create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25923116/android-set-random-colour-background-on-create)

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches

1. Using predefined colors [as in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25923418/1454173)

   > In colors.xml
   >
   > ```
   > <item name="blue" type="color">#FF33B5E5</item>
   > <item name="purple" type="color">#FFAA66CC</item>
   > <item name="green" type="color">#FF99CC00</item>
   > <item name="orange" type="color">#FFFFBB33</item>
   > <item name="red" type="color">#FFFF4444</item>
   > <item name="darkblue" type="color">#FF0099CC</item>
   > <item name="darkpurple" type="color">#FF9933CC</item>
   > <item name="darkgreen" type="color">#FF669900</item>
   > <item name="darkorange" type="color">#FFFF8800</item>
   > <item name="darkred" type="color">#FFCC0000</item>
   >
   > <integer-array name="androidcolors">
   >     <item>@color/blue</item>
   >     <item>@color/purple</item>
   >     <item>@color/green</item>
   >     <item>@color/orange</item>
   >     <item>@color/red</item>
   >     <item>@color/darkblue</item>
   >     <item>@color/darkpurple</item>
   >     <item>@color/darkgreen</item>
   >     <item>@color/darkorange</item>
   >     <item>@color/darkred</item>
   > </integer-array>
   > ```
   >
   > In onCreate()
   >
   > ```
   > int[] androidColors = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.androidcolors);
   > int randomAndroidColor = androidColors[new Random().nextInt(androidColors.length)];
   > view.setBackgroundColor(randomAndroidColor);
   > ```
2. Using Random RGB coloring [as in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32659086/1454173)

   > ```
   > Random rnd = new Random();
   > currentStrokeColor = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256),rnd.nextInt(256));
   > ```