# How can I change background with random time?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin

I'm new on Stack Overflow and I want to learn answer this question please don't give me negative reputation.

How can I change background color with random time and everytime on Android Studio ? I'm using Kotlin language.

```
var counter:Int =0

        if (Random.nextBoolean())
            background.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
        else
            background.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)

        btn_touch.setOnClickListener {

            counter += 1
            textCounter.text = counter.toString()
```

Comment: How often do you want the background color to change?

Comment: I want to change only green or red

Comment: _When_ do you want the background to change? Every second? Every time the user visits the screen? Every time someone clicks a button?

Comment: I want to change background random time for example 5 second after green and then maybe 1 second after will change red. Can i explain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fun coroutines answer:

```
    var loop = true
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        while(loop) {
            delay(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(Random.nextLong(5)))
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                when (Random.nextBoolean()) {
                    true -> background.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
                    false -> background.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This will change the color randomly between the two colors, with a random interval of 1-5 seconds.

You need the dependency in your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
         implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.3"
         implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.3'   
    }
```

Control the loop value to start and stop the randomisation. (perhaps in `onResume` & `onPause`.

You could make it choose random colors also using:

```
 background.setBackgroundColor(Random.nextInt(255))
```

Comment: I don't understand`GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)`  GlobalScope and Dispatchers are unresolved reference what should i do ?

Comment: @life4 updated it with the kotlin coroutines dependency you need to add :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code snippet

```
val maxDelay = 10000L
val handler = Handler()
var isRed = true;
val updateRunnable = object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        background.setBackgroundColor(if(isRed) Color.RED else Color.GREEN)
        isRed = !isRed
        handler.postDelayed(this, Random.nextLong(maxDelay))
    }
}
handler.post(updateRunnable)
```

Set `maxDelay` value as you need and don't forget to call `handler.removeCallbacks(updateRunnable)` when you don't need it anymore.

Comment: When i import `Handler()` method android studio has 2 section one of them `android.os` and the other `java.util.logging` what is the difference

Comment: I choose android.os it works i understand code . This was very helpful thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

you can add `CheckBox` when checked add green Background if not add red

```
btn_touch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener
        { compoundButton, ischecked ->
            if (ischecked) {
            background.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
            } else{
            background.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)

              }
        })
```

but if you want to add random every press give you Different color you can follow this question.
[Android: Set Random colour background on create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25923116/android-set-random-colour-background-on-create/25923418)

I hope it will help you .

Comment: sorry i don't wanna using checkbox i want to change background color random time.